# C# - UdpClient receives data using BeginReceive but does not receive data with ReceiveAsync

Tags: c#

I'm in the midst of testing some UDP Request code, which is supposed to send a message and receive a message back. This function runs over 20 times and I'd like to run it asynchronously.

`ExecuteUdpRequest` is the version which works, it uses `SendAsync` to send the message and `BeginReceive` to receive the message, it also times out correctly and gives the correct data.

`ExecuteUdpRequest2` which is the version I want to use, uses both `SendAsync` & `ReceiveAsync`, it:

1. Hangs forever (important to note - it does not crash, the output window still gives random bits of info about threads exiting with code 0)
2. Does not cancel based on the cancellation token given
3. Does not raise an exception & does not give any info on the output screen.

`ExecuteUdpRequest` - `BeginReceive` (the one that works)

```
private async Task<byte[]?> ExecuteUdpRequest(Uri uri, byte[] message)
{
    if (uri == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(uri));

    if (message == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(message));

    byte[]? data = null;
    IPEndPoint any = new(IPAddress.Any, ListenPort);

    try
    {
        using (UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient())
        {
            udpClient.Client.SendTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds;
            udpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15).TotalMilliseconds;

            Logger.Log($"sending message to {uri.Host}, returning.", source: "UdpRequest");

            int numBytesSent = await udpClient.SendAsync(message, message.Length, uri.Host, uri.Port);
            Logger.Log($"Sent: {numBytesSent}", source: "UdpRequest");

            var res = udpClient.BeginReceive(null, null);
            //data = udpClient.EndReceive(res, ref any);
            // begin receive right after request
            if (res.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
            {
                Logger.Log($"Received message from endpoint, returning.", source: "UdpRequest");

                #pragma warning disable CS8600 // Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
                data = udpClient.EndReceive(res, ref any);
                #pragma warning restore CS8600 // Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.Log($"No bytes received from UdpRequest", source: "UdpRequest");
                // here the client just times out.
            }
        }
    }
    catch(SocketException ex)
    {
        Logger.Log($"Failed UDP tracker message to {uri} for torrent {Torrent.InfoHash}: {ex.Message}");
    }

    return data;
}
```

`ExecuteUdpRequest2 - ReceiveAsync` (the one that hangs)

```
private async Task<byte[]?> ExecuteUdpRequest2(Uri uri, byte[] message)
{
    byte[]? data = null;

    if (uri == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(uri));

    if (message == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(message));

    int port = await Torrent.PortList.AwaitOpenPort();

    IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);

    try
    {
        using UdpClient udpClient = new(ep);
        
        Logger.Log($"Listening on : {ep}");

        udpClient.Client.SendTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds;
        udpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds;

        Logger.Log($"sending message to {uri.Host}, returning.", source: "UdpRequest");

        int numBytesSent = await udpClient.SendAsync(message, message.Length, uri.Host, uri.Port);
        Logger.Log($"Sent: {numBytesSent}", source: "UdpRequest");

        UdpReceiveResult? res;
        //var res = udpClient.BeginReceive(null, null);

        try
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            
            var timer = new Timer(state => cts.Cancel(), null, 5000, Timeout.Infinite);
            res = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync(cts.Token);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            res = null;
        }

        // begin receive right after request
        if (res != null && res?.Buffer != null && res?.Buffer.Length > 0)
        {
            Logger.Log($"Received message from endpoint, returning.", source: "UdpRequest");

            data = res?.Buffer;
        }
        else
        {
            Logger.Log($"No bytes received from UdpRequest", source: "UdpRequest");
            // here the client just times out.
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        Logger.Log($"Failed UDP tracker message to {uri} for torrent {Torrent.InfoHash}: {ex.Message}");
    }

    Torrent.PortList.SetPortUnused(port);

    return data;
}
```

Small note - the port stuff with `ExecuteUdpRequest2` works fine, it should still receive data back its a system which I've tested manually a few times already and is set in place as 2 ports can't listen on the same port.

I'm failing to see why `ExecuteUdpRequest` works but not `ExecuteUdpRequest2`

Comment: Are you calling this from a GUI application, and is the code blocking on the returned task?

Comment: GUI Application yes, this specific code is currently being run before the UI initializes so it just doesn't launch the application, it doesn't return anything, it gets stuck when calling ReceiveAsync

Comment: And is the startup code blocking on this code?

Comment: Why are you using `Begin/End` rather than the `Async` versions with `await`?

Comment: @Charlieface I have 2 versions, the async one doesn't work, it's written in the question, see ExecuteUdpRequest2

Comment: @StephenCleary it basically gets to the receiveasync and just hangs, it doesn't go into the GUI because right now I'm testing it before the UI code starts

Comment: How are you calling this `ExecuteUdpRequest2` are you using a blocking method such as `.Wait` or `.Result` ? You must `await` it. Also `timer` and `cts` need `using`, and a better method of cancelling `cts` would be instead to just create it with auto-cancelling: `using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(5000);`